# Lagging while typing

Tags: keyboard

I am using Ubuntu 14.04. But unexpectedly, I am facing a problem that while typing a lagging occurs. Can anybody tell me the cause and a way to solve this problem out ?

Thanks

Comment: Too little information here. Typing where, in just one application or in general? Maybe you have a rogue program using all CPU, try to run "top" in a terminal and see if there is some suspicious thing (or post a screenshot in the question if unsure).

Answer (score 0):

same here.
After a short period, minutes to hours, keystrokes lag and become intermittent.  In the  'terminator' terminal I can hold down a key to let it repeat, and it'll suddenly stop. This is on an RF keyboard, so I disabled BT, and wireless, with no effect.  Nothing helpfull in sys.log either